# Perl search in filesystem - display results on web

Tags: perl

Good day everybody,
I am not a programmer at all, so I would really appreciate your help.
I have a server that hold files in the following directory structure:

```
/usr/httpd/htdocs/statements
```

under this statements directory, I have numerous sub directories:
`ab, ac, ad` etc. These refer to different sites. 
Under the sites I have directories which is in the format of basically the year and month

```
201101
201102
```

There are lots of these directories which hold files with a .body extension. A typical example of such a file is:

```
S117873000.body
S117873000x.body
```

**I have a web interface where a user will enter a number to search for** eg: `S117873000`

HTML SEARCH:

```
    print "</select></td><td>
                <form method=POST action=/cgi-bin/search.pl>
                enter a number to search for:
                <input type=text name=query size=15>
                </td></tr><tr><td colspan=2><center><input type=submit value=Search <input type=reset>
                </center></form></td></tr>\n";
```

I have tried to write some perl to search recursively through these directories and display the results for the user in a link that he can click on. I have deleted most of what I have tried, so the following does not display much. I need to pull the argument from the web search, search recursively for the matching number(s) and display a link to it.

### search.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI qw(:standard);
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
my $dirs = '/usr/httpd/htdocs/statements/';
## Collect the value of 'query' submitted by the webpage
my $cgi = new CGI;
my $query=$cgi->param('query');

find( sub
{}
'$dirs');


sub return_html {
   print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
   print "<html>\n <head>\n  <title>Results of Search</title>\n </head>\n";
   print "<ul>\n";

   print "<li><a href=\......\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $query = $cgi->param('query');
print header;
use vars qw/*name *dir *prune/;
*name   = *File::Find::name;
*dir    = *File::Find::dir;
*prune  = *File::Find::prune;
find ( sub
{
  print 'Results:';
  /$query/ && print $name . "\n";
}, $dirs);
```

This should work or something very similar

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working with the code below. I just need to display the results with a hyperlink so that the users can click on it. Currently it displays all results in one line and no hyperlink.
/usr/httpd/htdocs/statements/ec/200501/T047906000x.body /usr/httpd/htdocs/statements/ec/200501/T047906000.body

Any ideas on how to display the results one on a line with a clickable hyperlink?

```html
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI qw(:standard);
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
my $dir = '/usr/httpd/htdocs/statements/';
## Collect the value of 'query' submitted by the webpage
my $cgi = new CGI;
my $query=$cgi->param('query');

print header();
print start_html();


# for the convenience of &wanted calls, including -eval statements:
use vars qw/*name *dir *prune/;
*name   = *File::Find::name;
*dir    = *File::Find::dir;
*prune  = *File::Find::prune;

#sub wanted;


# Traverse desired filesystems
File::Find::find({wanted => \&wanted}, '/usr/httpd/htdocs/statements/');
exit;


sub wanted {
    /^$query.*\z/s &&
    print("$name\n");
}

print end_html()
```